# Samsung Java SDK 1.2.2 for OSX

Tags: java, android, macos, sdk

I'm trying to find a  Samsung Java SDK 1.2.2 for OSX, is there anyone? In [Samsung Java SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/java/tools-sdks/New-Samsung-Java-SDK-1-2-2-release-28th-October-2010) I've just found one for Windows.
Thanks!

Comment: I have no facts, but the way Samsung _loves_ Apple I bet what you are looking for does not exist ;)

Comment: @jlordo Of course, Samsung has supplied every mobile CPU to Apple for years now, though this is likely to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Mac OS X support for the Samsung Java SDK.

Since you tagged this as Android, maybe you should take note of the following:

1. Android has its own, highly detailed and comprehensive, SDKs.
2. The Samsung Java SDK is not meant for use, or is compatible with, Android devices in any case.